# How is Kinect Data Read by ROS

Tags: ros, kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Does anybody know how kinect data is processed in ROS. as i know it has a RGB Data and a Depth Data usually stored in a .xed file. Anybody knows how its processed in ROS??

If its split into 2 files or seperate streams etc?? Does OpenNi do it for ROS??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55995/how-is-kinect-data-read-by-ros/) by [preetham.hegde](https://answers.ros.org/users/4262/preetham.hegde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS drivers simply interact with OpenNI by registering appropriate callbacks and receiving data from OpenNI through these callback functions. There are no .xed files, simply a callback for each stream of data (RGB stream + Depth Stream).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2